# Specific start and end 'x' coordinates for a Draggable div inside a parent div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble trying to create a formula that will be universal within a responsive website. I am using Bootstrap.

Specifically, I have a "timeline" div that is inside a border div. I have it so that it is draggable. I am trying to make it stop dragging when it reaches a specific point on either side of the timeline.

See it here: [Draggable Timeline](http://org4peace.org/michael/test/timeline/index.html)

Dragging the timeline right towards the first year is no problem. I have that working. It stops dragging where it is supposed to.

However, dragging the timeline left towards the last year, it stops dragging in a different spot depending on the window size.

When I think I have it working at one window size, I resize the window and it is off.

In the images below, that is the end result I am trying to achieve. The timeline should have a 15px margin on either end.

**The start Position:** (working)
[image]

**The End Position** (not working)
[image]

The timeline is dynamically generated by javascript. However for this problem we will keep it at 5000.4px in width.

This is my HTML:

```
 <div id="timeline-border" class="timeline-border">
      <div id="timeline" class="timeline">
      </div><!-- end timeline -->
 </div><!-- end timeline-border -->
```

Here is my scrolling code.

```
var timeline = document.getElementById("timeline");
    //set timeline width
    var timelineWidth = (numOfMonths*16.668);

    timeline.setAttribute("style","width:"+timelineWidth+"px;");
    var zIndex = 0;

    //timeline width: 5000.4
    console.log("timelineWidth: "+timelineWidth);

    // timeline parent width: 750
    var timelineBorderWidth = document.getElementById("timeline-border").offsetWidth;
    console.log("timelineBorderWidth: "+timelineBorderWidth);

    //timelineVisible: 735
    var timelineVisible = timelineBorderWidth - 15;
    console.log("timelineVisible: "+timelineVisible);

    //timeline hidden length: 4265.4
    var timelineHidden = timelineWidth - (timelineBorderWidth-15);
    console.log("timelineHidden: "+timelineHidden);

    //timeline offset left: 96.5
    var timelineLeftPos = $("#timeline").offset().left;
    console.log("timelineOffsetLeft: "+timelineLeftPos);

    //timeline offset left: 81.5
    var timelineLeftPosition = $('#timeline').position().left;
    console.log("timelineLeftPosition: "+timelineLeftPosition);

    //timeline offset from parent: 16
    var elem = $("#timeline");
    var offset = elem.offset().left - elem.parent().offset().left;
    console.log("timeline offset from parent: "+offset);

    // magicXNum: -4361.9
    var magicXNum = timelineHidden + timelineLeftPos;
    console.log("magicXNum: -"+magicXNum);


$( "#timeline" ).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        scroll: false,
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            $('#posX').text('#timeline offset.left: ' + xPos);

                if (ui.position.left >= 0) {
                    ui.position.left = 0;
                } else if (ui.position.left <= -magicXNum){ //small size -4632){
                    ui.position.left = -magicXNum;// small size -4632;
                }
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {

            }
    });
```

Here is the console output.

```
timelineWidth: 5000.4
timelineBorderWidth: 750
timelineVisible: 735
timelineHidden: 4265.4
timelineOffsetLeft: 96.5
timelineLeftPosition: 81.5
timeline offset from parent: 16
magicXNum: -4361.9
```

Comment: Its more accurate to use the widthofyear#divs*numberofyears, because offset is calculated by the edge of the full document which is adjusting itself

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The width of a year is set by css at 200px +1 pixel border-left. The width of a month is also set by css at 16.668px + 1 pixel border-left. So, I know the precise width of the timeline. The timelineWidth variable is accurate.

Comment: ok, i went throught the code

Answer (score 0):

Goto Line 53: do some subtraction and addition there like:

```
Line 53: var magicXNum = timelineWidth - timelineBorderWidth + 30;
```

Now it has to update every time when the user stretches the window..

> So your MagicXNumber is now a **Dynamic**MagicXNumber by adding this below
>   Line 53:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    timelineBorderWidth = document.getElementById("timeline-border").offsetWidth;
    magicXNum = timelineWidth - timelineBorderWidth + 30;
    console.log("magicXNum: "+magicXNum);
});
```

Bootstrap makes the timeline jump out of place when stretched out.

Are you going to add a marker on your calendar? So when it does jump the timeline centers itself to the marker?